# What rights are needed to register an application within Portal.Azure.Com

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using the portal.azure.com, I'd like to register an application we've been developing (Angular Web Portal). When I try to register it to start the process of using Azure Active Directory, I'm not allowed to, insufficient rights. 2 part question, 1 what rights are required, 2 how to find the holders of these rights.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1)**

You need to satisfy either (any) of the conditions (from least privileged to most privileged):

- Your Azure Active Directory must allow "users to register applications":
  [image]
- You are in Application Developer Role
- You are in Application Administrator Role
- You are in Cloud Application Administrator Role
- You are in Global Administrator Role

**Answer to question 2)**

You have to talk to your IT Administrator / Global Administrator. The easiest way is to contact your it administrator and ask them. Or you can try finding this out of the portal (depending on the settings you may, or may not have access to this part of the portal):
[image]

If you see that screen click on "Global Adminsitrator" and you will see who to contact...